# Unique Square Root Neighbourhood in Topological Group

Tags: lie-groups, topological-groups

For a Lie Group $\mathfrak{G}$ and any neighbourhood $\mathcal{V}\subset\mathfrak{G}$ of the identity $\mathrm{id}\in\mathfrak{G}$, $\exists$ neighbourhood $\mathcal{U}\subset\mathcal{V}$ of $\mathrm{id}$ such that every element of $\mathcal{U}$ has a unique square root in that neighbourhood, *i.e.* $\forall z\in\mathcal{U}\, \exists x\in\mathcal{U}\text{ s.t. }x^2=z$ as well as $x,\,x^2,y,\,\,y^2\in\mathcal{U},\,x^2 = y^2\Rightarrow\,x=y$.

I am almost certain that one can prove the same thing for a general topological group. It's easy to prove the first bit, *i.e.* since $x\mapsto x^2$ is cts and $\mathrm{id}^2=\mathrm{id}$, choose any neigbourhood $\mathcal{V}$ of $\mathrm{id}$ then by continuity $\exists$ a neighbourhood $\mathcal{U}$ of $\mathrm{id}$ such that $\mathcal{U}\,\mathcal{U}\subseteq\mathcal{V}$, then $\mathcal{W}=\mathcal{U\,U\cap U}$ is a neighbourhood of $\mathrm{id}$ wherein every element has a square root. But I can't seem to show that this square root is unique.

**Question 1:** Can anyone give a proof that the square root in $\mathcal{W}$ above is unique?

I would be also interested in any proof that needs to use the venerable Prof Gleason's "No Small Subgroups" (NSS) condition, *i.e.* for a topological group for which one can say there is a neighbourhood of the identity $\mathcal{G}$ wherein there are no subgroups other than the trivial one $\{\mathrm{id}\}$. Otherwise put, the powers of any $\gamma\in\mathcal{G}$ to wit $\mathrm{id},\,\gamma^{\pm1},\,\gamma^{\pm2},\,\gamma^{\pm3},\,\cdots$ must eventually "escape" from $\mathcal{G}$ *i.e* $\exists n\in\mathcal{N} \ni \gamma^n\not\in \mathcal{G}$. On reflexion, I think that my "intuition" that there should be a proof for a general topological group may be flawed and may be instead grounded on this kind of NSS behaviour: for Lie groups, uniqueness works because squaring puts a member a distance $d$ (measured, say by the Euclidean norm in the Lie algebra) from the identity at least a distance $(2 - \epsilon) d$, where you can bound $\epsilon$ by taking a small enough neighbourhood.

**Question 2:** As for question 1, but also assuming the no small subgroups condition.

**Possible Question 3:** If you can prove uniqueness with NSS condition but not otherwise, can you give a proof, or even any reasonably thought out hunch or opinion as to whether the NSS condition is essential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [Cantor cube](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_cube), $\:\operatorname{id}\:$ has square roots other than itself that are arbitrarily close to itself.

The [$\:tri$adic rationals$\:$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_rational) do not have small subgroups but do have

elements arbitrarily close to $\:\operatorname{id}\:$ that don't have square roots.

In *abelian* groups, $\;\;\;\; x+x \: = \: y+y \;\; \implies \;\; \{\operatorname{id}\hspace{.02 in},x\hspace{-0.05 in}+\hspace{-0.04 in}(\hspace{-0.03 in}-y)\hspace{-0.02 in}\} \:$ is a subgroup $\:\:\:$.

In *abelian* groups, if there are elements with more than one

small square root then there are small subgroups of order 2.

The only part this answer leaves open is whether or not there is a non-abelian

group that satisfies the no small subgroups condition but has arbitrarily

small non-$\operatorname{id}$ elements with multiple correspondingly small square roots.

Comment: +1 Some interesting examples, Ricky, many thanks. Now you've mentioned it, I came very close to your NSS proof of uniqueness in Abelian groups, but, since I wasn't assuming commutativity it didn't work for me. But thanks for making explicit a special case: I'm a little nearer to an answer and have learnt something, so much appreciated.